# How to set a HTTP proxy server in all Lighttpd SSL configuration

Tags: ssl, lighttpd

I've configured my Proxy server as HTTPS only. Now I want that for a specific URL with pattern ^/backend(.*)$ the requests are redirected to port 8080 (with **HTTP** instead of HTTPS).

If I configure the proxy server without HTTPS I could do it this way:

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/backend(.*)$" {
    proxy.server  = ("" => (
            ("host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => 8080)
        ))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SSL isn't supported by lighttpd on the back end.

I would suggest either using HAProxy instead of lighttpd as a reverse proxy or just use HTTP for your back end connections.